# switch between activities, how can I know the previous activity is in my application or not

Tags: android, android-activity

How can I know the previous activity is in my application or other applications? I want to do something when the previous activity is not in my application.

Comment: Its not clear what you want !!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Answer (score 0):

So i understand you have activity that can be navigated to from inside of your application, as well as from external application.

When you navigate to this activity from your application, you can set special parameter, so that new activity will know that your application called it, like this:

```
Intent newActivityIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
newActivityIntent.putExtra("activity_started_from_my_application", true); //Special parameters
startActivity(newActivityIntent);
```